# Comparing factors in data.frame

Tags: r

The raw data I have imported into R has 3 columns: (I) Name, (II) Statistic, 
(III) #Cells

The Names given in the Name Column are verbose, for example:

```
01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_001.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD8a subset/integrin B7 subset    
01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_003.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD4 subset/CD103 subset
01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_004.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD4 subset/CD73 subset

(table not shown as there are several hundred rows).
```

To simplify this column, I wish to compare the names and remove the part shared between each sample (with Tube_0*.*. wildcard). For example, the above 3 should become:

```
CD8a subset/integrin B7 subset
CD4 subset/CD103 subset
CD4 subset/CD73 subset
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved? I do not wish to use

```
01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_0*.*.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live
```

inside a variable and use

```
as.data.frame(sapply(NameofDataFrame,gsub,pattern=VariableName,replacement=""))
```

as the exact names will change between experiments

Comment: You can still provide a sample of a large dataset like this: (1) use dput() to print the structure of the first 5 rows of your data, for example, like this: dput(yourData[c(1:5),]); (2) copy/paste that structure output into your question.

Comment: Your edit helped clarify the question, but in order to give an accurate solution, we have to have more information about what the unique cases look like. The easiest way to provide this is through sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **gsub** for this:

```
gsub("(.*)+Live+/","",x)

[1] "CD8a subset/integrin B7 subset" "CD4 subset/CD103 subset"       
[3] "CD4 subset/CD73 subset"
```

Sample data:

```
x <- c(
"01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_001.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD8a subset/integrin B7 subset",
"01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_003.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD4 subset/CD103 subset",
"01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_004.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD4 subset/CD73 subset")
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves the question, please mark it as a solution to help the community know.

Comment: @Snelling97 Mark solutions as answers by clicking on the check mark next to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

x <- c(
  "01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_001.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD8a subset/integrin B7 subset",
  "01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_003.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD4 subset/CD103 subset",
  "01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_004.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live/CD4 subset/CD73 subset")

str_match(x, '.*/Live/(.*)')[,2]
```

Comment: To the down-voter: please provide an explanation. I'd like to correct my answer if there's something wrong. I thought I delivered on exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: OP's words: `I do not wish to use 01Sep17 Trm diffn_Tube_0*.*.fcs/Lymphocytes/Live`

Comment: My mistake. I read OP as not wanting that as *output* rather than not wanting that as *input*. I edited my answer.